# How can I delete files on a read-only file system?

Tags: files, osx, readonly

I have an encrypted .dmg file with some useless files that I need to delete to make space. How can I delete them without having to convert them into a read write system and then back? (Would take 4~5 hours).

Like I said, it's read only so `sudo rm -rf` tells me that It can't delete it due to it being a read only file system.

Comment: Check if [this](http://superuser.com/questions/146045/how-to-write-to-a-mac-osx-read-only-filesystem) can help you.

Comment: Deleting files from the middle of a large encrypted file will in itself be a time consuming task, even if it were a writeable system. It will have to be deconstructed and reconstructed in any case.

Comment: To use a shadow file with the attached compressed image, make the changes and re-create a compressed, encrypted image from it as suggested in Max Felker's answer (http://superuser.com/a/806321/316104) in @taliezin's link seems to be an attractive solution to me.

Answer (score 5):

A *read-only* file system can only be read (therefore it is named *read-only*).

To delete files on this file-system you have to remount it read-write.

Comment: Looks like it's not so simple as to mount *.dmg read/write. They need to be unpacked and reconstructed, just like `tar` archives.